# how can i connect to a password proctected wifi named as "A"

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, wifi

How can connect to a specific wifi which is password protected?

Scenario: There are four wifi networks but my app needs to connect to specific one whilst providing a password.

Answer (score 6):

You can't there is no public API to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually select a wifi network from the settings.