# how can set select wifi network through programming as alternate of UIRequiresPersistentWiFi

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can i connect to a password proctected wifi named as “A”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213862/how-can-i-connect-to-a-password-proctected-wifi-named-as-a)

I need to hardcode the wifi password and how can I connect to specific wifi network when it is available as alternate of UIRequiresPersistentWiFi(which shows a Dialog box for wifi).
Please help my task is that I need to connect a network names as A and its password in "2322"

Comment: Please refrain from reposting the same question. If you have further details, edit the original question insteead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, there is no public API to do this.

Also don't ask the same question twice.